# Relationship between flags D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS and D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

Tags: linux, glibc, yocto

I am using a 32 bit version of a Linux build in Yocto.  I want to add support for timestamps after 2038, so in the local `.conf` file I added:

```
TARGET_CPPFLAGS += "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
TARGET_CPPFLAGS += "-D_TIME_BITS=64"
```

The second flag is necessary to build the image with the first flag according to the `glibc` manual. In one of the glibc files (`features-time64.h`) there is the following code fragment:

```
#if defined _TIME_BITS
# if _TIME_BITS == 64
#  if ! defined (_FILE_OFFSET_BITS) || _FILE_OFFSET_BITS != 64
#   error "_TIME_BITS=64 is allowed only with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
#  elif __TIMESIZE == 32
#   define __USE_TIME_BITS64    1
#  endif
# elif _TIME_BITS == 32
#  if __TIMESIZE > 32
#   error "_TIME_BITS=32 is not compatible with __TIMESIZE > 32"
#  endif
# else
#  error Invalid _TIME_BITS value (can only be 32 or 64-bit)
# endif
#endif
```

In the image I have, among others, the `zlib` program, which has the `D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1` flag set by default. In `zlib` code there is a following piece of code (`gzguts.h`):

```
#ifdef _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#  ifndef _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#    define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE 1
#  endif
#  ifdef _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
#    undef _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
#  endif
#endif
```

The default flag `D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1` in `zlib`, causes undefining the `FILE_OFFSET_BITS` flag and the above code from `features_time.h` file reports an error :

> _TIME_BITS=64 is allowed only with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

So the image will not build because `zlib` does not want to build. Why can't I have both `D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1` and `D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag set at the same time? Can I somehow work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is still an open issue at Github: https://github.com/madler/zlib/issues/447

But in the comments someone mentioned this way to workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801397/glibc-build-with-flags-file-offset-bits-64-and-time-bits-64-fails/72854884#72854884

I stepped into the same issue today while building an image on the Long Term Support branch "kirkstone".